# SpeechToText conversion using Python - SpeechRecognition and PyAudio

Tags: python

The terminal executes the code but its stuck at "Start Processing..."
This used to work first. I have tested it. But now after a few months there seems to be some issue

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio


r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('Start speaking...')

    audio=r.listen(source)

try:
    text=r.recognize_google(audio)
    print('The text is: {}'.format(text))

except:
     print('Audio is not audible!!')
```

Comment: There is no "Start Processing...", please edit to reflect.

Comment: I meant Start Speaking

Comment: START PROCESSING---> START SPEAKING